# Wobbly synth sound

Tags: sound-design, synthesis, replication

I'm trying to reproduce this sound
https://clyp.it/pjws3e4v

It's from Scooter's "No fate" song. 
I think it's just some saw shaped thing with a high sustain on the envelope and high freqs cut off.
Here is where I got so far: https://clyp.it/b3jwwkxd

Any tips on how to get closer to the original? I tried adding some chorus and "flanger" fx to make it sound more "aggressive" but it's not enough apparently

Answer (score 1):

I think your really close and on the right track. I would first try adding some med-hard distortion and a Trans mod plugin on an FX track with automation and blending. If that does not work try duplicating the original track adding the same plugins and maybe high pass the new version and low pass the original and play with the dry/wet on the mid-highs.

You are defiantly close I think its going to be a combination of slightly distorting the high end and messing with the attack to make the over all sound more punchy and in your face.

Hope this helps
-Jeff